# show retrieve data in drop down list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller code

```
<?php




class Booking_Controller extends CI_Controller{



        public function __construct(){


            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Books_model');

        }


    public function view()
    {

        $data['result']=$this->Books_model->get_restaurants();

        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);


    }


}
```

And its model code

```
<?php


class Books_model extends CI_Model{



    public function __construct(){

        $this->load->database();


    }

    public function get_restaurants()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id, names FROM restaurants ";
        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Plz guide me what code i written in view file that i get name list in dropdown form....

Comment: So, what's not working? What's it doing wrong? How do you want it to work? What are you expecting to see? These are all things you should include in your question so that it makes it EASY to answer. Not easy to close as people are unsure what you are asking.

Comment: actually  i want to show the restaurants name list  come from db in the text field..plz guide me how i do this

Answer (score 3):

In your controller:

```
$result = $this->Books_model->get_restaurants();
$data['select'] = Array();
foreach($result as $r){
    $data['select'][$r->id] = $r->names;
}
$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
$this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);
```

In your view:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('restaurant', $select);  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

write following code to show dropdown in views.

```
<select name="">
<?php foreach($result as $row){?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->names;?></option>
 <? }?>
</select>
```

$data['result'] is converted to $result variable in view and hence you can use it as above mentioned.

Comment: thanx a lot @ shanuingh my code is now in runnig form....just replace the <? with <?php.....thanx a lot